# Will I lose data in Windows if I upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade

I have an Aspire E14 with dual boot, first option Ubuntu and then Windows 10. I want to upgrade, the message appears on the start screen. But my concern is what can I hope with the dual boot and my files in Windows? Windows OS has some critical info for me and I don't want to lose it.

Comment: I've upgraded my Linux systems for years, both servers and desktop (dual or triple(!!) booting). Never had a (apparent) problem. That said, it's ALWAYS better to have an up-to-date backup of any data you **can't affort to loose**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always assume that anything altering your hard disk (installing an OS, for instance, which usually changes the partitions) will completely erase the storage device, and plan accordingly.

No, it probably won't -- but if you make a full backup before you start, you'll avoid being back on here to ask "how can I recover my Windows partition after Ubuntu's installer overwrite it?"

Answer (score 0):

Dual boot depends on the grub EFI file, which shouldn't be affected by the upgrade process. If, for some reason, the upgrade does muck up your dual boot setup, the computer should default to booting into Windows. If this happens, you can do one of two things: either add grub as a trusted EFI file in the BIOS/UEFI settings, or disable SecureBoot.

Regardless, your files on Windows should be fine. Assuming you're not using full-disk encryption, you can boot from a live USB and access data on both partitions.